# MariaDB Cluster - data consistency for updates and auto_increment

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have two different MariaDB servers and plan to merge data into one database and create MariaDB Cluster with 3 nodes. I read about Galera and multi-master replication - which MariaDB Cluster use and have some questions. And I not use transactions, foreign keys, etc...

1) If I understand it well - unlike of MySQL Cluster on Galera I do not have to worry about auto increment values. Config auto_increment_offset is not needed with Galera. Is this true?

2) I read many articles and discussions about data consistency and replication but still have questions. If application not use transaction and for example run 10x query "UPDATE a SET b=b+1 WHERE c=1 LIMIT 1". Can I be 100% sure that "SELECT b FROM a WHERE c=1 LIMIT 1" return right value? On one slideshare presentation I read - "Data does not belong to a node - Node belong to data". So, it's true that Galera replicator take all care about consistency and no changes in application is needed?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Yes, Galera takes care of auto increments for you, but you will get lots of missed ids, so make sure your fields are big enough (e.g. you might need a smallint somewhere whereas without missing ids you could have got away with a tinyint).

2 - Yes, no changes should be needed to the application, except for occasionally you might get deadlocks. You should come up with a system to check error messages automatically and if you get errors like `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` and `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` then redo the query and it should go through ok. The data will remain consistent. There is also a Galera setting for automatic retries, but we found it was better to try them again yourself. Obviously you shouldn't be using `mysql_query()` at all, but for the purposes of a simple to follow example, you could swap your queries to use something like this instead of your usual query function

```
function vio_mysql_query_deadlock_safe($query, $db = null) {
    $deadlock_retries_done = 0;
    $deadlock_retries_max = 10;
    while ($deadlock_retries_done < $deadlock_retries_max) {
        if (is_null($db)) {
            $q = mysql_query($query);
        } else {
            $q = mysql_query($query, $db);
        }
        if ($q === false) {
            $error = mysql_error();
            if ($error == 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' || $error == 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction') {
                $deadlock_retries_done++;
                continue;
            } else {
                throw new Exception($error . '. Query: ' . $query);
            }
        }
        return $q;
    }
    throw new SQLException($error . '. Re-tried with deadlock ' . $deadlock_retries_done . ' times. Query: ' . $query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is old question and I run cluster over month. In beginning I have some conflicts (but no deadlocks). This is perfectly solved with sending all writes (insert,update,delete,...) to only one server. And for better balancing I give to "write" server lower priority in haproxy. So S1 have all writes and read balancing is S1 20%, S2 40%, S3 40%. From many tests, this is best solution and all works fine. In peak hours I have about 150k users online and no conflicts :-)

Comment: I'm pleased it's working well for you, we found sometimes at busy times that a write might happen on one node and not instantly be there on another node to read. We had to switch on `wsrep_causal_reads="ON"` on `my.cnf` as slightly slower performance (not noticeable though) was better than somebody placing an order but the order not existing when the got the confirmation page a fraction of a second later! Surely if you split your reads and writes, you're not taking advantage of one of Galera's best features (multi-master)?